# How to compare two list?

Tags: java

I have two lists, I would like to compare them with each other and introduce differences, but my code does not work, what could be the problem? How would you do that?

```
private List<Payment> rbsList;
private List<Payment> partnerList;

public void compare() {
    try {
        for (Payment rbs : rbsList) {
            for (Payment partner : partnerList) {
                if (partner.getAccount().equals(rbs.getAccount()) && partner.getSum() == rbs.getSum()) {
                    rbs.setExist(true);
                    partner.setExist(true);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError | ConcurrentModificationException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    notMatchedRBS = rbsList.stream().filter(r -> !r.isExist()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    notMatchedPartner = partnerList.stream().filter(p -> !p.isExist()).collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Comment: catch OOME to then print a stack trace and just keep going with your code? same for comodex? Just delete the try and catch - the default catch mechanism is 'exit this method right now and keep exiting methods until the entrypoint', which is vastly superior. Update your IDE templates.

Comment: Your code seems fine. Provide the actual data (what values do `rbsList` and `partnerList` have when you run this code, what is `getAccount()`, what does its `equals` method look like, same for `.getSum()`. The error lies in one of those aspects, not in the code you pasted.

Comment: It would be worthwhile defining what you mean by "my code does not work".

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to be ok. It's Important to define what equals means to you, let's say:

-> Two accounts are equals if both has the same Id.

I recommend you to check if `Account`'s equals is properly defined. The same happens with `getSum()`.

Comment: It would be useful to be explicit and highlight the core principal here. That being the need for a custom `equals` method on the `Account` class as otherwise it will just be doing an object comparison - as opposed to business logic comparison (the gist of what you're saying). This may be more helpful to potentially new java programmers.

Answer (score 0):

1. In payment class, add implementation for equals() then you can just do:
   partner.equals(rbs) in the if.
2. Consider using Java stream instead of the two for loops:

   ```
        List<Payment> differences = rbsList.stream()
            .filter(element -> !partnerList.contains(element))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```